# Find and classify the spectrum of a linear operator

Tags: spectral-theory

I am given a linear operator $T$ on $l^2$ that maps an element $x = (\xi_k)_{k\ge1}$ to $Tx = (\xi_2, \xi_1, \xi_3, \cdots)$. (It just swaps the first two elements). I now need to calculate and classify the spectrum of this operator.

I started by calculating $(T - \lambda I)^{-1} =: R_{\lambda}$. I believe that in this case this is $R_{\lambda}x = (\xi_2 + \lambda, \xi_1 + \lambda, \xi_3 + \lambda, \cdots...) = (T + \lambda I) x$. Now I didn't really have an ansatz so I just tried to calculate wether $R_\lambda$ is bounded

$$
||R_\lambda x||^2 = ||(T + \lambda I)x||^2 = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} |(\xi_2 + \lambda, \xi_1 + \lambda, \xi_3 + \lambda, ...)|^2
$$

The way I see it, this sum only converges for $\lambda = 0$. All other lambdas would turn the sequence into a non-null sequence, so the sum can't converge anymore. What this tells me is that every $\lambda \in \mathbb{C} \setminus \{0\}$ is part of the continuous spectrum of $T$. However we learned a theorem that the spectrum of a bounded operator on a Banach space is contained in the disk $|\lambda| \le ||T||$. Afaik $l^2$ is a banach space and $||T|| \le 1$, but the calculated spectrum is definitely outside this disk.

So what am I missing? It is probably something obvious, as I said I'm just starting to try to understand spectral theory.

Comment: One could simplify analysis by noting that $T(x) = x - 2 \langle x,y \rangle y$, where $y$ is the unit vector
$$
y = \frac 1{\sqrt{2}}(1,1,0,0,\dots).
$$

Comment: Wouldn't this result in $Tx = (-\xi_2, -\xi_1, \xi_3, \cdots)$?

Comment: Ah you're right.  That should be $y = \frac 1{\sqrt 2}(1,-1,0,0,\dots)$

Answer (score 1):

You are making a basic mistake. You are writing $\lambda I x$ as $(\lambda, \lambda,...)$. But it is $\lambda (\xi_1,\xi_2,...)=(\lambda\xi_1,\lambda \xi_2,...)$

Also you formula for $R_{\lambda}$ is wrong. The solution of $(T-\lambda I) x=y$ is not $x=(T+\lambda I) y$.

Comment: Ah, I see. Okay so going from this, then $||R_\lambda x||^2 \le ||x||^2 + |\lambda|^2 ||x||^2 = (1 + |\lambda|^2) ||x||^2$? Now the spectrum seems to be the whole of $\mathbb{C}$, so it's still not inside this disk?

Comment: @Lauchmelder See my edit. For formula for the resolvent is more complicated.

Comment: Okay, so $(T - \lambda I)x = (\xi_2 - \lambda \xi_1, \xi_1 - \lambda \xi_2, \xi_3 - \lambda \xi_3, \cdots)$. I know that for $\lambda \ne 1$, the inverse of this doesn't exist, since this sequence wouldn't even be part of $l^2$ anymore (it would turn $x$ into a non-null sequence, therefore not converging absolutely in the series). So $\lambda \ne 1$ are all part of the point spectrum of $T$?

Comment: Try to solve the equation $(T-\lambda I)x=y$. After writing down $x(=R_{\lambda} y)$ in terms of $y$ see when $y \to R_{\lambda} y$ is a bounded linear map. I don't undestand how you are saying that the inverse does not exist for $\lambda \neq 1$.

Answer (score 0):

We see that $T^2=I$, hence

$$(*) \quad \sigma(T^2)=\{1\}.$$

If $x=(0,0,1,0,0,....)$ then $Tx=x$, hence $1$ is an eigenvalue of $T$, thus $ 1 \in \sigma(T).$

If $x=(-1,1,0,0,....)$ then $Tx=-x$, hence $-1$ is an eigenvalue of $T$, thus $ -1 \in \sigma(T).$

$(*)$ implies now that

$$ \sigma(T)=\{1,-1\}.$$